# Google Spreadsheets: Is there a HTTP request function?

Tags: google-sheets

Does Google Spreadsheets have a cell function that lets me do HTTP requests like

POST the contents of this cell to http://www.mysite.com/input or

GET the XML at http://www.mysite.com/feed.xml

?

Or can I write a custom function that does so?  Or is there a more conventional way of doing what I want to do? (using Spreadsheets to talk to REST APIs)

Answer (score 1):

For getting contents of a cell to your website use the Google Spreadsheet API.
Here you can find a simple example of retrieving JSON feeds from Spreadsheets Data API:
https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

Since this link may be moved due goole updates here's a copy of the script element:

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/feed/key/worksheet/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=myFunc
```

... where **feed** is the type of feed, **key** is the key of the spreadsheet you want to retrieve, the worksheet is the positional or unique identifier of the worksheet, and **myFunc** is the name of your callback function that is passed the JSON object.

For getting XML from a web ressource use the function:
**IMPORTXML(URL; XPath)** e.g. 
`importXML("http://www.example.com/feed.xml";"/path/inXML")`